# Postgres 9.5 xlog fills all disk space in replication setup with replication slot

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.5

I have replication set up on Postgresql 9.5 using replication slot. I have one primary and one slave machine, both Ubuntu 14.04 with a cluster called main that is in a directory other than the default. On both servers separately the database worked as expected (before setting up replication), including access from another Ubuntu server.

On the primary, I have in the postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
max_replication_slots = 8
archive_timeout = 60
max_wal_senders = 8
wal_keep_segments = 100
logging_collector = on
```

I added a replication user to pg_hba.conf:

```
host    replication     repuser         [iprange]         md5
```

I restarted the db and created a replication slot like so (as sudo -u postgres psql postgres):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_create_physical_replication_slot('repslot001');
```

On the slave machine, I started with the pg_basebackup:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -v -h [ipofprimary] -U repuser -D [mydatadir] -R -Xs -P
```

I added to postgresql.conf:

```
hot_standby = on
```

My recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=repuser password=geheim host=[ipofprimary] port=[port] sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
primary_slot_name = 'repslot001'
trigger_file = '[datadirectory]/finish.recovery'
recovery_target_timeline='latest'
```

I restarted the db and everything seemed fine. I went home at this point.

The next day my master server had crashed because the disk was full:

```
PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.11700": No space left on device
```

I googled around and found that this happens if the archive_command, as set in postgresql.conf on the master, is incorrect or missing.

But it is my understanding that when using replication slots I don't need an archive_command (and so, I didn't set an archive command). What mistake did I make?

If you need more information to be able to answer this, please let me know. But note that I need to continue my work, I am now trying if I can promote slave to master and clean up the old broken master. I'll make a backup of the data directory, which also has the logs. Also note that this is a test setup, I will not lose any data. Only when I'm confident I know how it works and how to set it up correctly will I start using replication in a production environment.

Thank you.

Edit.
The mistake I made was that I mixed up using archiving and using replication slots (thanks Frankie for your patience). I now have the following in my postgresql.conf - and it is working as expected:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 8
max_replication_slots = 1
hot_standby = on
```

I removed the archiving settings `archive_mode` and `archive_command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a hot standby master/slave setup, without, eg point in time recovery, just set archive_mode to false or remove it from your postgres.conf. Otherwise you'll have to come up with a storage plan so you have enough space which might involve setting up archive_command to copy the archive to a disk with enough space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the problem: I did not set the archive command, it was commented out in postgresql.conf.

Comment: No, because that's my question. Everywhere where I read it says that I don't need an archive command, because I'm using replication slot. You suggest to remove archive_command from my postgresql.conf. That was the setting in the first place: commented out.

Comment: No, I suggested removing **archive_mode**, not **archive_command**. Reading through [this link](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-replication-slots/), archiving appears to have nothing to do with physical replication slots at all.

Comment: Just get rid of all options to do starting with archive.

Comment: Ah, I misread. I mainly followed [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/denishpatel/out-of-the-box-replication-in-postgres-94pg-con) (on slide 37 the setup for postgresql.conf is given). They turn on archive_mode but do not give any archive_command (so I kept it commented). I will give your link a thorough look.

Comment: In those slides, before slide 25 is the old way and after slide 25 is the new way. The reason it talks about archiving in the first place is to demonstrate you can now use pg_receivexlog and point it to the physical replication to do archiving more easily. You don't need to do either to get replication working, but rather if you would like point in time recovery, which is a different feature.